# Cannot enable migrations in VS.2017 with ASP.NET Core web application

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I started to build my ASP.NET web application with the ASP.NET Core template. I noticed it has already two files in the ~\Data\Migrations folder one naemd *_CreateIdentitySchema.cs and the other ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.

At first it was complaining that i had Powershell 2 so I installed v3. 
Then I installed the package EntityFramework (v6.1.3) from the package manager because somehow that was not installed from the template as it was the case in VS.2015.

Now it gives me an error like "**Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s):** " and then  a bunch of things.

```
 $domain.SetData('contextProject', $contextProject)
 CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException
 Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation,
```

Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable."
At C:\Users\Devel.nuget\packages\entityframework\6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:720 char:5
+     $domain.SetData('startUpProject', $startUpProject)

I am using VS.2017 Update 1, I get the impression this "core" thing is complicating life more than making it simpler.

Comment: For me helped setting startup project to something else than ASP.NET Core web application.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with EF6: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/231

Answer (score 2):

I have do the following:

1. *Set as StartUp Project* my unit test project,
2. Set platform to Any CPU,
3. Added an empty constructor to the Context (without calling *base("name=XXX")*).

Then I have issued this command **Enable-Migrations**

> Enable-Migrations -ProjectName "MyProjectWithContext"
>   -ConnectionString "Data Source=.\SQL;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" -ConnectionProviderName   System.Data.SqlClient

Same things for **Add-Migration**

> Add-Migration -Name MyName -ProjectName "MyProject" -ConnectionString
>   "Data Source=.\SQL;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Integrated
>   Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" -ConnectionProviderName
>   System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: First setp was all that was needed for me

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if any of this helps: I had the same issue after placing my enties in a project targetting .NET 4.6.2, but using the "new" MSBuild-Syntax (I think that's what it is called).

Projectname.csproj (the one containing the code from the entity framework) looked like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
```

I now recreated the project using VS 2017's "Windows Classic Desktop - Class Library (.NET Framework)" template (basically: Copy all the code and setup all dependencies again).

Now, the Projectname.csproj looks like this (legacy MSBuild? Not sure how to call it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```

I still could add the "new" project as a reference to the project containing the ASP.NET Core stuff. And, more importantly, using "Add-Migration" on the project containing the EF types now works (EDIT: I still need to follow the advise given by Damian Drygiel: Startup project has to be a different project with a valid app.config).

Honestly speaking, I am still not sure whether using this workaround is a good idea or not as it leads to mixing the two types of projects / MSBuild versions. Not sure what the implications are. So far, it seems to work.

My take-away so far: Don't try to use .NET 4.6 with the "new" project format. This does not seem to work well at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

hello everyone i was also having the same error the main reason behind this is that your class library is of type Standard library ,use a class library of .net framework type and the issue is solved,install entity framework and run enable-migration command its works,it should contain a context class.

Comment: This does not provide any value to the answers above